# Which example for a do-while loop?

Tags: c++, logic, do-while

Inside of a do-while loop and if else statements is it in best interest for at the end of your statements you change a variables value and use that to create your while boolean expression, or is it best to set your while expression to always being true, and then use a break statement in your if else statements.

To clarify, here are the two methods.

```
do
{
cout << "What is your choice?" << endl;
cin >> choice;

 if(choice == 1)
  {
    cout << "You chose 1" << endl;
    doWhileModifier = 1;
  } else {
    cout << "That's not a correct choice" << endl;
    doWhileModifier = 0;
  }
}
while (doWhileModifier == 0);
```

VS

```
do
{
cout << "What is your choice?" << endl;
cin >> choice;

 if(choice == 1)
  {
    cout << "You chose 1" << endl;
    break;
  } else {
    cout << "That's not a correct choice" << endl;
  }
}
while (true);
```

I originally did it the first way, but now I'm leaning towards the second example.

Input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use `while(choice != 1)`, etc.

Comment: I guess I sort of jumped to branching them out instead of including them all in a single boolean expression. Is it correct to add in, if there were multiple choices, something like: `while(choice !=1 || choice !=2 || choice != 3)`?

Comment: It depends on what your program needs to do. There isn't always one single encompassing way to do things. For example, if you have a set of options that are all valid (let's say 3 valid choices), you could do:`do { ... } while( choice < 0 || choice > 3);` and have a `switch(choice) { ... }` inside. That's just one way of doing it, there's other ways too.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this code and seeing which out of the three you think is most appropriate? 

http://pastebin.com/fhkhdPK6

Comment: You can do what I said in my 2nd comment for your first `do { ... } while ( ... );` statement. For the 2nd statement: `do { prompt, get input } while ( input < 0 || input > 10000 );` is clearer. I suggest you get a good book on programming in general and start from there if these are the type of questions you have. I recommend Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (whatever the newest edition currently is).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'm actually taking a class right now, but we kind of brushed over do-while loops. I'll ask him when I go to class next though, thank you for the book suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both do-while loops get the job done so it is really up to your personal preference on which do-while loop you want to have in your code. But if you like the second one better than I would suggest just doing a while loop and not  a do-while loop since it is simpler, easier to read, and it does the same thing as the do-while loop anyways.